# posting xml data from java to rails (restful service)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, xml, post

I'm trying to post an xml document from java to a rails application. I have a hard time writing the http request
Here's my java code:

```
        Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);
        String path = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/mycontrollers.xml";
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        wr.write("POST +path+ " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        wr.write("Host: http://127.0.0.1:3000\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Length: " + xmldata.length() + "\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
        wr.write("\r\n");
        //Send data
        wr.write(xmldata);
        wr.flush();
```

In return I have : Not Found: /mycontrollers.xml

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what do you get if you access http://127.0.0.1:3000/mycontrollers.xml from the browser?

Comment: Are ruby app answers requests from browser? From telnet on this port? Why not using `commons-httpclient`

ps you forgot an quote (") at line 4, before `+path`

Answer (score 0):

Why not using already implemented solutions from caucho: [hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) or [burlap](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/burlap-notes.xtp) library? This is available for ruby and java.

And did you try to post the xml with [more simple tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put) (e.g. the firefox plugin)?

I think you will need to [implement the rails side](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/11/02/rest-on-rails.html) for you job too.
(I know that one could easily retrieve xml from rails but not the otherway around I think)

Answer (score 0):

From the error you're seeing it sounds like you don't have the routing setup to handle `/mycontrollers.xml` in your Rails application.  Are you using the resource helpers or have you defined a custom route?

If you've defined your own route you'll need to add `.:format` to the route so that Rails can pick up the content type from the url.

Another alternative would be to send the `Accept` header in your `POST` and send it to `/mycontrollers` rather than `/mycontrollers.xml`.